# Pipe Express JS Request & Response to Streams

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream, blob

I'm trying to build a file streaming api using node streams, backed by [s3-blob-store](https://github.com/jb55/s3-blob-store) (or any other api that implements [abstract-blob-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/abstract-blob-store)) but I can't seem to get the express request or response objects to pipe the data into the appropriate read and write streams.

I'm using a service based architecture similar to [FeathersJS](http://feathersjs.com):

```
create(data, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const { request } = params;
      if (typeof request === 'undefined') {
        reject(new Error('blob-service: no request object attached to params. Make sure to use the middleware'));
      } else {
        const contentType = request.get('Feathers-Content-Type');
        const streamId = shortid.generate();
        const extension = mimeTypes.extension(contentType);
        const id = `${ streamId }.${ extension }`;
        const writeStream = this.Model.createWriteStream({ key: id });
        writeStream.on('error', reject);
        writeStream.on('finish', () => {
            resolve({
             [ this.id ]: id
            });
         });
        request.pipe(writeStream);
      }
    });
  }
```

`this.Model` is an instance of S3 blob store. Since `request` is a streamable object, I should be able to do `request.pipe(writeStream)` but although the request returns a `201`, no data is actually being written.

And on the downloading side, how would I pipe a read stream into an express response object?